# $.getJSON not pulling

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I haven't been able to find the answer so I made a temporary workaround - and I can't use that in the end file.

when the json array is directly in my javascript file, everything works correctly.

Moving it to it's own file and then using $.getJSON returns nothing. Even alert("hi") inside doesn't show.

structure of json array in file name text.json :

```
var settable = {"playerinfo" : [{"seated": "player1","name": "Mack","stuff": "5025"},
{"seated": "player2","name": "Ahle","stuff": "5030"}]);

var hand = {"hands" : [{"carda": "aa", "cardb": "bb"}, {"carda" : "cc", "cardb": "cc"}]);
```

to be used in something like:

```
$("#div").text(settable.playerinfo[i].name);
```

THANKKK YOUUUUU!

And the next step is filling the "aa" etc with AJAX

how do i get this?

Comment: Can we see the code that gets the JSON?

Comment: Also I think seeing the php that handles echoing the json would be awesome. My only guess right now is that you arent using `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

you have invalid *json*. Replace the last `)` with `}`

Answer (score 1):

If that is what your text file looks like, then You are sending javascript, not json. Format your json to look something like this:

```
{
    "settable" : {
        "playerinfo" : [
            {
                "seated": "player1",
                "name": "Mack",
                "stuff": "5025" 
            },
            {
                "seated": "player2",
                "name": "Ahle",
                "stuff": "5030" 
            } 
        ] 
    },
    "hand" : {
        "hands" : [
            {
                "carda": "aa",
                "cardb": "bb" 
            },
            {
                "carda" : "cc",
                "cardb": "cc" 
            } 
        ] 
    } 
}
```

Also, you should give an error handler to your getJSON that will tell you what the problem is, which in this case is a JSON syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)